# How to make the soft keyboard show automatically when page onload?

Tags: javascript, html, input, frontend

In a html5 page, there is a input element, and I need to make the soft keyboard automatically show and focus on the input element, I tried to add attribute 'autofocus' on the 'input' element, but this way just automatically focus on the element, but the soft keyboard didn't show.

Comment: You need to trigger focus and click events on the input for showing soft keyboard on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

$('input[name="field-name"]).focus();

Should do the trick, via $(document).ready(function () {})...

Comment: I have tried, but doesn't work, it can focus automatically but the soft keyboard doesn't show.